# Having two buttons in one React form (or something similar)

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

**Solution:** how to implement two functions (with two buttons) using the same information from a single form:

```js
  async function myHandleSubmit(data, event){
      if(event.nativeEvent.submitter?.id === "submit1"){
        console.log("Ref1");
      }else if(event.nativeEvent.submitter?.id === "submit2"){
        console.log("Ref2");
      }
  }

  <Form key={1} onSubmit={handleSubmit(myHandleSubmit)}>
       // More code...
       <FormButtonTop left id="submit1" type="submit" value="Button A" />
       <FormButtonTop right id="submit2" type="submit" value="Button B" />
       // More code...
  </Form>
```

Comment: you need to import react ,btw is your component functional or class component?

Comment: I did it. But, when I reach the page, I got that error (even before of clicking the button). It´s a functional component. @JatinParmar

Comment: well i assume index.js has class component,add this like 
import React from 'react' at the top

Comment: @JatinParmar it is already there: `import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react';`. There's no errors when I launch the app. Just when I reach the page which contains the form.

Comment: well React is default export from 'react', so should not be inside {},just remove it from {} and add it in a new line

Comment: it will be more helpful if you tell me, is your component is functional component or class component

Comment: it´s a functional component. Ok, at least the page is working. But when I click the buttons I´m getting this new error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clicked')`. It seems this reference `ref1.current.clicked` is not working.

Comment: okay since its functional component instead of React.createRef you can replace same code with useRef

Comment: working now, but... it's supposed to print something by console, right? It's not displaying anything on the console.

Comment: ref.current.clicked is not a valid ,let me cross check

Comment: you should unaccept the answer,its need to be corrected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243554/discussion-between-joncarre-and-jatin-parmar).

Comment: I got a solution and I've updated the question. Tyvm for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have single handler for form submit and you want to perform different action based on which submit button is clicked?right .

you can do this by following steps

**1.create state for button clieked**

**2.onclick of button set which button is clicked**

**3.at the time of submission check which  button is clicked inside submit handlers**

for example consider the following code

```
//infunctional component you can use useRef hook
 const [clickedButton,setClicked] = useState("");
```

assign click handler  to both buttons like this and set clicked button value on click

```
 <FormButtonTop onClick={()=>{setClicked("firstButton")}} left id="submit1" type="submit" value="A generator" />
 <FormButtonTop  onClick={()=>{setClicked("secondButton")}} right id="submit2" type="submit" value="B generator" />
```

finally inside your submit handler use clickedButton to check which button is clicked and make a call to appropriate function as shown below

```
 funciton handleSubmit(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  if(clickedButton==="firstButton"){
     //form is submited with submit1 click
     //do your code 
   }elseif(clickedButton==="secondButton"){
      //form is submited with submit2 click
         ///do your code here for submit2 click
    }else{
        //form is submited by pressing enter key
         // do your code to handle enter key press
      }
   
}
```

created an example code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sound-bdizsv?file=/src/App.js).

since form can also be submited using enter key,you will need to set clickedButton="" when enter key is pressed on any text box

Comment: hello and thanks for helping. I´ve updated the question because using your solution I´m getting a new error :(